# Finding order of conditions met in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a set of data like so in a `pandas.DataFrame`:

```
    A      B      C
1   0.96   1.2    0.75
2   0.94   1.3    0.72
3   0.92   1.15   0.68
4   0.90   1.0    0.73
...
```

and I'd like to figure out the order in which the data meets conditions. If I were looking for A decreasing, B decreasing, and C increasing in the example above, I would get ABC, as A is first to meet its condition, B is second, and C is third.

Right now I'm running through a loop trying to figure this out, but is there a better way to do this leveraging the capabilities of Pandas?

Comment: `df.sort_values(['A','B','C'], ascending=[False, False, True])`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do that.  This makes the assumption, which matches the context of your question, that we can describe the possible conditions as the previous value was less than or greater than the current value.

#### Code:

```
def met_condition_at(test_df, tests):
    # for each column apply the conditional test and then cumsum()
    deltas = [getattr(test_df.diff()[col], test)(0).cumsum() for col, test
              in zip(test_df.columns, tests)]

    # the first time the condition is true, cumsum() == 1
    return (pd.concat(deltas, axis=1) == 1).idxmax()
```

#### How?

1. We take the `.diff()` of each column
2. We then apply the test to see when the diff changes signs
3. We then `.cumsum()` on the Boolean result and find when it is `== 1`
4. The index when `== 1` is the index when it first changed direction

#### Test Code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_fwf(StringIO(u"""
       A      B      C
       0.96   1.2    0.75
       0.94   1.3    0.72
       0.92   1.15   0.68
       0.90   1.0    0.73"""), header=1)
print(df)

tests = ('lt', 'lt', 'gt')
print(met_condition_at(df, tests))

print(''.join(met_condition_at(df, tests).sort_values().index.values))
```

#### Results:

```
      A     B     C
0  0.96  1.20  0.75
1  0.94  1.30  0.72
2  0.92  1.15  0.68
3  0.90  1.00  0.73

A    1
B    2
C    3
dtype: int64

ABC
```

Comment: This is very much the kind of thing I was looking for. I had begun leveraging diff() and idxmax() for a solution of my own, but this is way more organized.